# What are the different ways of including libraries in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, linux

Allow me to preface this question by letting you know that I have no formal CS education and have been self-learning C++.

I would like to understand what the different ways of including third party libraries in a project are.

How to identify how a project is to be included if there is an interesting library on github?

I've read about concepts of dynamic and static linking in a windows context however I am still somewhat not clear about them.

Comment: "How to identify how a project is to be included if there is an interesting library on github?" The best way is to read their documentation. If they have no documentation, you will have to examine their build scripts to see what options they offer. If there are no build scripts... Well. You have a bit of work ahead, either looking for an alternative or figuring out how the @$&% thing works.

Comment: A library is *not* a header file (which *describes* a library). A compiler handles *translation units*. Your question is too broad (and needs several books to be answered)

Answer (score 2):

Libraries contain implementations of functions, regardless of being static or dynamic. A library contains m function implementations, of which a subset n < m is exposed to the user. In C++, for these n functions the library normally offers a header file provided to you for inclusion, a list of so-called function prototypes. Depending on what header you include, and what function you have used in your project, the linker memorizes the prototypes of such external functions and demands you to link the appropriate library against your executable to satisfy the unresolved prototype symbol.

Function implementations of static libraries are welded at compile time into your executable. Function implementations of dynamic libraries remain exactly in their location, there's just a stub welded into your executable that will transfer control over to the dynamic library upon a call to it.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, you just need to do following steps to include/referece a C++ library:

- Add the heade file (`*.h` or `*.hpp`) directory to your project's include paths.

  - `#include` the `xxx.h` in your source code files,  to call the functions/methods/interfaces.
- Add libaray:

  - For static lib (`*.lib` on Windows or `*.a` on Linux), add the lib to your project's library paths.
  - For dynamic lib: just make sure the `*.dll` (or `*.so`) are in the same directory of your project output (like `*.exe` or your lib), for running or to publish/deploy.

Comment: On Linux you'll better not put the `*.so` in the same directory.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch : Your answer is right for a common or system lib `*.so` .  But I think his question is not about a common/system lib (seems from github and for learning c++), so I'd suggest to put them in a same directory with his output (exe/lib) -- except his project is a large one and need deployment design.

Comment: No, doing that requires setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or the executable's [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) explicitly, and that is difficult for newbies (even when coding tiny projects). So your hint is wrong.

Comment: I don't think he can run/debug his exe without using `rpath`  (gcc/g++ compilation option or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in environment variables permanently or temporarily each time before running). Right? :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is wrong. Please try.

Comment: It'll be valuable if it's true so I'll learn from this and correct my knowledge. Thanks **BasileStarynkevitch** !  I'll do it on idle. And @GNettlefold maybe you can try it out before me. :) ^_^

Comment: @Quanmao I am still trying to find my bearing around C++ (and what the different development environment options etc are). The reason I asked this question is because I am mainly familiar with Python, which has a very convenient package manager.

Comment: I see. C++ package referencing (in fact no such term in c++ at all) is very different from and raw compared with `C# NuGet` / `Scala/Java maven`. If you want to build a reference/import a C++ library, I think the easiest way for a newbie is using Visual Studio on Windows, then you can just follow the my answer above to configure it in Visual Studio; Otherwise on Linux, you probably need to write a `makefile` (using IDE like `CodeBlocks `? `Eclipse C++ `?) . **Just search the keywords** above (plus Windows or Linux, VS or makefile) and `dllimport` etc. on web. Believe yourself, it's easy.

Comment: @Quanmao Thank you, your post was very helpful :)